# Finding multiple substrings using boundaries in Java

Tags: java

Alright so here is my problem. Basically I have a string with 4 words in it, with each word seperated by a #. What I need to do is use the substring method to extract each word and print it out. I am having trouble figuring out the parameters for it though. I can always get the first one right, but the following ones generally have problems.
Here is the first piece of the code:

```
word = format.substring( 0 , format.indexOf('#') );
```

Now from what I understand this basically means start at the beginning of the string, and end right before the #. So using the same logic, I tried to extract the second word like so:

```
wordTwo = format.substring ( wordlength + 1 , format.indexOf('#') ); 
//The plus one so I don't start at the #.
```

But with this I continually get errors saying it doesn't exist. I figured that the compiler was trying to read the first # before the second word, so I rewrote it like so:

```
wordTwo = format.substring (wordlength + 1, 1 + wordLength + format.indexOf('#') );
```

And with this it just completely screws it up, either not printing the second word or not stopping in the right place. If I could get any help on the formatting of this, it would be greatly appreciated. Since this is for a class, I am limited to using very basic methods such as indexOf, length, substring etc. so if you could refrain from using anything to complex that would be amazing!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have to use substring then you need to use the [variant of indexOf that takes a start](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28int,%20int%29). This means you can start look for the second `#` by starting the search after the first one. I.e.

```
wordTwo = format.substring ( wordlength + 1 , format.indexOf('#', wordlength + 1 ) );
```

There are however much better ways of splitting a string on a delimiter like this. You can use a [StringTokenizer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html). This is designed for splitting strings like this. Basically:

```
StringTokenizer tok = new StringTokenizer(format, "#");
String word = tok.nextToken();
String word2 = tok.nextToken();
String word3 = tok.nextToken();
```

Or you can use the [String.split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) method which is designed for splitting strings. e.g.

```
String[] parts = String.split("#");
String word = parts[0];
String word2 = parts[1];
String word3 = parts[2];
```

Comment: That first bit was exactly what I was looking for, thank you. I didn't know that you could put multiple arguments inside of indexOf. I'm excited to start learning more like the things you talked about after it! Thank you again and have a wonderful night/day!

Comment: Do note that `StringTokenizer` is now considered to be a *legacy class* and it is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. The suggested alternative is to use the `split(..)` method of *String* class

Comment: @Sujay I disagree. It's not deprecated in [java 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html). While in the past StringTokenizer was used to make up for the lack of split, there are cases where StringTokenizer is still more suitable. Describing it as a legacy class is inaccurate.

Comment: @EdC: Well if you go down a little bit on the same link that you've posted, you would notice that the Javadoc itself specifies the following: *StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use the split method of String or the java.util.regex package instead.* :)

Comment: @Sujay, Fair enough :). Surprised they haven't deprecated it if they're now considering it legacy. Still places where it is better suited but they are rare.

Comment: @EdC: Actually, I understand that `split()` brings in a lot of flexibility and that's why its usage is encouraged. But just like you, I still wonder why a class considered to be a legacy is still not *depricated* :(

Comment: @Sujay, absolutely there is more flexibility with split, but it comes at a performance cost. If you're using it in a tight loop StringTokenizer can be quicker because there is no need to execute a regex for a simple match. But if you're getting to that level of performance you probably need to use CharacterSequences and avoid the cost of producing new char arrays for new Strings.

Answer (score 2):

You can go with `split()` for this kind of formatting strings.

For instance if you have string like,

```
String text = "Word1#Word2#Word3#Word4";
```

You can use delimiter as,

```
String delimiter = "#";
```

Then create an string array like,

```
  String[] temp;
```

For splitting string,

```
temp = text.split(delimiter);
```

You can get words like this,

```
temp[0] = "Word1";
temp[1] = "Word2";
temp[2] = "Word3";
temp[3] = "Word4";
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `split()` method to do this with `"#"` as the delimiter

```
String  s = "hi#vivek#is#good";
String temp = new String();

String[] arr = s.split("#");

for(String x : arr){

  temp = temp + x;
}
```

**Or if you want to exact each word**... you have it already in `arr`

```
arr[0] ---> First Word
arr[1] ---> Second Word
arr[2] ---> Third Word
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you've a look at the [Javadoc for String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) before you proceed further.

Since this is your homework, I'll give you a couple of hints and maybe you can solve it yourself:

- The format for *subString* is `public void subString(int beginIndex, int endIndex)`. As per the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int%29) for this method:

> Returns a new string that is a substring of this string. The substring
>   begins at the specified beginIndex and extends to the character at
>   index endIndex - 1. Thus the length of the substring is
>   endIndex-beginIndex.

Note that if you've to use this method, understand that you'll have to shift your beginIndex and endIndex each time because in your situation, you'll have multiple words that are separated by #.

- However if you look closely, there's another method in String class that might be helpful to you. That's the `public String[] split(String regex)` method. The [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) for this one states:

> Splits this string around matches of the given regular expression.
>   This method works as if by invoking the two-argument split method with
>   the given expression and a limit argument of zero. Trailing empty
>   strings are therefore not included in the resulting array.

The `split()` method looks pretty interesting for your case. You can *split* your String with the delimiter that you have as the parameter to this method, get the String array and work with that.

Hope this helps you to understand your problem and get started towards a solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a home work, it may be better to have try to write it your self. But I will give a clue.

Clue:

> The `indexOf` method has another overload: `int indexOf(int chr,
>   int fromIndex)` which find the first character `chr` in the string
>   from the `fromIndex`.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

From this clue, the program will look something like this:

1. Find the index of the first `'#'` from the start of the string.
2. Extract the word from 0th character to that index.
3. Find the index of the first `'#'` from the character AFTER the first `'#'`.
4. Extract the word from the first `'#'` that index.
   ... Just do it until you get 4 words or the string ends.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you're forced to use `String#substring`, but as others have mentioned, it seems like the wrong method for the kind of functionality you need.

`String#split(String regex)` is what you would use for such a problem, or, if your input sequence is something you don't control, I would suggest you look at the overloaded method `String#split(String regex, int limit)`; this way you can impose a limit on the amount of matches you make, controlling your resulting array.